# Mysql aliasing error in nested query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with 3 tables, A `VOLUNTEER` table, a `TRAINING_EVENTS` table, and a `TRAINING_INSTRUCTOR` table.

The `VOLUNTEER` table contains information about a person marked by an auto incremented `Vol_ID`.

The `TRAINING_EVENTS` table contains dates and times for an event marked by an auto incremented `Event_ID`. It also assigns each event an `Hours_Credited` field, which indicated how many credit hours a volunteer receives for being an instructor for that particular event.

The `TRAINING_INSTRUCTOR` table contains the `Vol_ID` and `Event_id`. (Indicating which volunteer is the instructor for an event).

I would like to have a query that tells what volunteers will be instructors at events in August.

The following code is what I attempted to use, but results in an error saying that every derived table must have its own alias.

```
SELECT V.Vol_ID, V.Fname, V.Lname 
FROM VOLUNTEER AS V, 
( SELECT TI.Event_ID,  
  FROM TRAINING_INSTRUCTOR AS TI, TRAINING_EVENTS AS TE  
  WHERE MONTH(Event_Date) = 8 AND TI.Event_ID = TE.Event_ID
) 
WHERE V.Vol_ID = TI.Vol_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the error because you did not provide an alias to the derived table (subquery in the from clause). Actually, you need to use the alias of the subquery in the join operation:

```
SELECT V.Vol_ID, V.Fname, V.Lname 
FROM VOLUNTEER AS V, 
(SELECT TI.Event_ID,

    FROM TRAINING_INSTRUCTOR AS TI, TRAINING_EVENTS AS TE

    WHERE MONTH(Event_Date) = 8 AND TI.Event_ID = TE.Event_ID) as t
WHERE V.Vol_ID = t.Vol_ID;
```

But you do not even need the derived table here, just join the 3 tables on each other:

```
SELECT V.Vol_ID, V.Fname, V.Lname 
FROM VOLUNTEER AS V
INNER JOIN TRAINING_INSTRUCTOR AS TI ON V.Vol_ID = TI.Vol_ID
INNER JOIN TRAINING_EVENTS AS TE ON TI.Event_ID = TE.Event_ID
WHERE MONTH(Event_Date) = 8;
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
SELECT V.Vol_ID, V.Fname, V.Lname
FROM VOLUNTEER as V, 
(SELECT TI.Event_ID,
FROM TRAINING_INSTRUCTOR AS TI, TRAINING_EVENTS AS TE
WHERE MONTH(Event_Date) = 8 AND TI.Event_ID = TE.Event_ID) as TI
WHERE V.Vol_ID = TI.Vol_ID;
```

The problem is that you don't have a name set for the temp table that you set up in the from clause.

You also can't use TI in the last line of your query because it was only an alias for the temp table. I used it on the last line of my query because that's what I named the temp table.

Last thing: you don't need the AS keyword, you could just write the query like this if you want:

```
SELECT V.Vol_ID, V.Fname, V.Lname
FROM VOLUNTEER V, 
(SELECT TI.Event_ID,
FROM TRAINING_INSTRUCTOR TI, TRAINING_EVENTS TE
WHERE MONTH(Event_Date) = 8 AND TI.Event_ID = TE.Event_ID) TI
WHERE V.Vol_ID = TI.Vol_ID;
```

Comment: Temp table is not the same as derived table!

Comment: Oh, maybe I used the wrong terminology then. But what I had should still work

Answer (score -1):

As Matthew said, there is the `TI` alias missing, but also in your subquery you should include `TI.VOL_ID`, like this:

```
SELECT V.Vol_ID, V.name
FROM VOLUNTEER V, 
(SELECT TI.Event_ID, TI.VOL_ID
FROM TRAINING_INSTRUCTOR AS TI, TRAINING_EVENTS AS TE
WHERE MONTH(Event_Date) = 8 AND TI.Event_ID = TE.Event_ID) TI
WHERE V.VOL_ID = TI.VOL_ID;
```

But you always can do the `JOIN` as Shadow posted.

Comment: Thank you. This works well. However, some people are scheduled to be instructors multiple times in August and therefor I get multiple rows for some volunteers. Is there any way to solve that? I am assuming something to do with the Event_Date field in the TRAINING_EVENTS table.

Comment: @ZL4892 this is a different question and you should ask it separately providing sample data, output, and expected output.

Comment: You should only add the `group by`, and Shadow is right about the separate question.